# Doubts about the effective potential in Newtonian gravity

Tags: energy, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

I'm studying for a physics exam in a CS degree and the professor introduced the effective potential related to gravitation.

Given $\vec v_r$ the component of the velocity of a planet that is parallel to the radius $\vec r$ of the orbit, $\vec v_t$ the component that is perpendicular to the radius and $\vec L$ the angular momentum.

Kinetic energy: $\vec K = \frac{1}{2}m\vec v^2 = \frac{1}{2}m\vec v_r^2 + \frac{1}{2}m\vec v_t^2 = \vec K_r + \vec K_t $

Since $ \vec L = m\vec r \wedge \vec v = m \vec r \wedge (\vec v_r+\vec v_t) = m\vec r \wedge \vec v_t $  then the absolute value $L = mrv_t\sin(\theta) = mrv_t$ that is costant, since gravity is a central field.

Then $v_t = \frac {L}{mr}$ and $K_t = \frac{1}{2}mv_t^2  =\frac{1}{2}m\frac{L^2}{m^2r^2}$

Potential energy: $V(r) = -G \frac{Mm}{r}$

Effecive potential: $V_{eff} = K_t(r) + V(r) $

Here the graph of $V_{eff}$ (not made by me):

[image]

Till here it should be all correct, but **here my (wrong) reasoning**:

Since the velocity $\vec v$ must be always tangent to the orbit, then at the aphelion and at the perihelion $ \vec v_r$ = 0, because $\vec v_t $ is already tangent there. So at the aphelion and at the perihelion $K_r = 0$ and the total energy is $ E = K_t(r) + V(r)$, that is exactly the formula of the effective potential. But since gravity is a conservative field, the conservation of $E$ applies, then $ E = K_t(r) + V(r)$ not only at the aphelion and perihelion, but at all points of the orbit. So $ E = V_{eff}$.

So, if I have a planet in orbit, and I want to calculate $E$, I can take any point of the orbit, calculate $r$ and use it to calculate $E$, and I would get the same result for $E$ no matter the $r$ chosen. But if I look at the graph, or just at the function $V_{eff}$ this is obviously false, since $V_{eff}$ has at best two solutions for $r$. So there must be something wrong in my reasoning. But **where is the mistake?**

Here is **another doubt**:

I don't understand why $V_{eff}$ allows us find the different kinds of orbits. 
 I also don't understand why in the graph $E = 0 = V_{eff}$. This is something that seems to support my (wrong) reasoning, so I'm confused. And even if my reasoning wasn't wrong I would be confused anyway, since in that case I wouldn't understand why $V_{eff}$ gives us the aphelion and perihelion and not also any other point of the orbit.

I searched on the Internet for some clarifications and I found that the effective potential is indeed a potential energy, but, if I understood correctly, not for gravitation. The point of equilibrium for that potential energy is magically (for me) a stable circular orbit, and I absolutely don't understand why.

Comment: What you're forgetting is that the effective potential doesn't contain _all_ of the kinetic energy, it only contains the kinetic energy due to angular motion. So it's not true that $E = V_{eff}$, it's $E = K_r + V_{eff}$.

Comment: I know that, and that's another contradiction with my reasoning, that says: "since $E = V_{eff}$ at the aphelion and at the perihelion, because there $K_r = 0$ then, by the conservation of $E$, $E = V_{eff}$ in every point of the orbit." And I want to know what's wrong with this reasoning exactly.

Comment: @emanueleascani Your argument is equivalent to saying, "since $f(0) = g(0)$, we must have $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$".

Comment: Agh, that's right! And the fact that the energy remain constant doesn't mean anything, because the effective potential doesn't remain constant! Thank you, first doubt solved. I'll reason a bit on the other one in the light of this.

Comment: Well now I also understand why the effective potential gives us the different kinds of orbits: It's precisely because the effective potential is the total energy at the aphelion and perihelion.